# Grounding on second floor

Tags: grounding

I need to ground an upper floor shack, but I do not know very much about grounding. I have a Pathfinder dipole by Radio Wavz and I don't believe I need any RF grounding, but as for safety and lightning ground, I am confused about what I need. I assume I need a lightning arrestor, ground rod, and my radio plugged into a surge protector, but I am not sure. I am pretty sure that my dipole includes a balun as well as a counterpoise. The coax will also be very high off of the ground because I am using the side of my house as a place to hold the antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use a surge and lightning arresters, maybe a UPS that will cut you off the main when the voltage is too low or too high is good too. The most important thing to keep in mind, when lightning strikes near you, whether coming from the antenna or utility side, the whole area floats up and down so it's important that everything be grounded together so everything floats up and down together. A ground rod for the antenna and a ground rod for the utility ground by itself is not enough and not low enough in impedance but the 2 grounds must be connected together with a strong wire with low impedance.

[image]